# CMS using grapes js in next js

Tags: next.js, content-management-system, webflow, grapesjs

I'm developing a website builder using Grapes JS (Next.js). Could someone provide guidance on creating a CMS similar to Webflow? Please guide me through the fundamental steps, as I'm unsure where to begin.